# How an interface knows whick class' implementation to use?

Tags: php, oop, interface

First of all, let me clarify my understanding of an interface.

**Real World Scenario**

In a real-world scenario, any vehicle having an engine must implement the functionality of the start engine. A CAR cannot be a CAR without an engine and the same goes for a motorbike. In programming terms, both Car and Bike classes must have a startEngine() method to be a Car & a Bike. But How? Here interfaces come into play. Interfaces enforce some classes or objects to implement specific methods to make the class more in sync with concrete reality.

**The Problem**

Let's assume I have a VehicleController class and I want to call startEngine() methods of Car and Bike classes by implementing
VehicalInterface on both Car and Bike classes.

```
interface VehicalInterface {
    public function startEngine();
}
```

```
class Car implements VehicalInterface {
    public function startEngine() {
        // Start the engine of CAR
    }
}

class Bike implements VehicalInterface {
    public function startEngine() {
        // Start the engine of BIKE
    }
}
```

```
class VehicleController extends Controller
{
    public function start(VehicalInterface $vehical)
    {
        $vehical->startEngine();
    }
}
```

My question is if a user wants to start the engine of a bike, let's say in a game, how VehicalInterface will decide that bike's class' implementation be used?

Comment: What programming language is this? Please tag. Different languages solve this in different ways

Comment: It's PHP. I have added a tag now. @RaymondChen

Comment: @DarkBee, can you please explain in general OOP context where our program will decide to use specific class implementation? In other words, how the program will decide that the bike's engine is going to start?

Comment: You don't use a `VehicleInterface` instance to call `start` (cause the interface itself cannot be instantiated)

Comment: When you ask "how" it knows which class to call, are you asking about how PHP internally knows? The php source code is on https://github.com/php/php-src if you want to study the implementation of PHP itself.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a simple definition of what an `interface` is:

> An interface is basically a contract in which you can define what methods a class has
> to obey/implement.

Now let's have a look at the question you are asking:

> How/where is decided which class definition to call when an implemented method is called?

The answer I'm gonna give could be hard to comprehend:

**The actual type of the object does not matter**

The type could be a `Motorcycle`, `Car`, `Bus`,... As long as the object implements the interface `VehicalInterface` we can be certain the method `startEngine` actually exist.

How the `Vehicle` actually starts the engine, or start driving, does not matter for the program, it can be done by turning the key, pulling a rope, pushing it downhill. It does not matter in any way, as long as the vehicle just starts to drive/roll.

This concept is basically called `abstraction`.

By implementing an interface to a class, you are also appointing an (extra) type to your class. This can actually be seen in your own code as well

```
public function start(VehicalInterface $vehical)
```

The code above will tell the interpreter that the argument passed to the method `start` should have the type `VehicalInterface`, by doing so the interpreter will also know the method `startEngine` exists and can be called.

---

Here is another example that is maybe easier to understand.

Imagine you go shopping. You put everything you need inside the basket and you want to check-out and you go the cashier.

In order to know the price the customer has to pay, every items needs to be scanned and every items has to report it's price to the cashier in order to know the total amount the customer has to pay.

```
<?php
    class Checkout {
        protected $total_price = 0.00;
        
        public function scanItems(array $items) {
            for($items as $item) {
                $this->total_price += $item->getPrice();
            }
            return $this;
        }
        
        public function getTotalPrice() {
            return $this->total_price;
        }
    }
```

```
    interface ICartItem {
        public function getPrice();
    }
    
    class Apple implements ICartItem {
        ...
        public function getPrice() {
            return $this->getUnitPrice() * $this->getWeight();
        }           
        ...
    }
    
    class Cereal implements ICartItem {
        ...
        public function getPrice() {
            return $this->getUnitPrice();
        }           
        ...
    }
    
    class Curtain implements ICartItem {
        ...
        public function getPrice() {
            return $this->getPricePerSquareFoot() * $this->getArea();
        }           
        ...
    }
```

As you can see above, the "crucial" part for the class `Checkout` is that it needs to know the price of an item. It does not care how the price is calculated, it only has to be certain it receives back a certain price so it can calculate what the total price is that the customer has to pay.

---

By using the interface `ICartItem` in the example above, we can be sure that if the shop suddenly starting selling new items, .e.g. `UnknownItem`, the class `Checkout` doesn't needs to be modified, as long as `UnkownItem` implements the interface `ICartItem`

Comment: Mandatory comment: `PHP` is not the greatest language to learn about the concept of `Interfaces`. If you really want to learn more about the proper use of interfaces I'd suggest you look into some java tutorials. It will make more sense as you can use typed lists in java e.g. `List<ICartItem>` instead of just an array.

Comment: Thanks, man, really good example to make the explanation easy to understand and to generalize my understanding of Interfaces. As far as your given example, I understood the point you are trying to make, but still, my question is the same. 

According to you

"How the Vehicle actually starts the engine or starts driving, does not matter for the program, it can be done by turning the key, pulling a rope, pushing it downhill. It does not matter in any way, as long as the vehicle just starts to drive/roll."

Comment: Yes, It really doesn't matter how the engine starts but the thing that does matter for me is I want to start the engine of a BIKE only. How my program will know that it must start the engine of a bike, not a car because it's a USER's CHOICE, which vehicle he wants to ride? In your scenario. you have a list of items and you want to calculate the prices for each respective item using an interface exposed by each object of the class. But in my scenario, I only want to start the engine of a BIKE only, not a Car. 

The bike's engine is starting based on a user's choice.

Comment: The difference is the USER'S CHOICE. What if I want to get the price of the Curtain only, not all products?  Where in the program I'll decide that the price should be calculated of Curtain?

Comment: You could explicitly ask to only handle curtains by checking it's type, e.g. `if ($item instanceof Curtain) $this->total_price += $item->getPrice();`. That's why I added in my answer that you actually assign an extra type to the class.

Comment: @UmarRaza If your question is "How can I check whether the interface came from a Bike?" then that's what you should have asked, instead of asking "How do interfaces find the concrete type?" Because people will answer the question you asked, not the question you want the answer to.